# How to get big Vista icons for a shortcut created with a VS2008 Setup and Deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, icons, setup-project, shortcut

First I made an app and I set its application icon to a icon I made. That icon has 256x256px in it, and it works good in windows vista (256 size gets used when really large icon).

I've made a setup project, that installs the app I made, and I added a shortcut to the desktop. The icon of the shortcut won't get big, it stays +- 48x48 maximum. It is as if the setup project changes the icon to remove the big version from it. The icon of the app itself is good, just the shortcut isn't

Shortcut icon pointing to the icon embedded in the app didn't work. Pointing to a separate icon file didn't work either.

How do I get the shortcut to use the correct icon, the one with 256 size included?

Edit: a scriptable solution would be awesome!

Comment: It seems that the same problem exists still with visual studio 2010 :( ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Orca to replace the icons in the MSI file.

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs-net-general/13054/Setup-and-Deployment-Vista-style-high-res-icons-on-advertised